# Directory is generating instead of excel file

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI on android to export an excel file for my offline database. While creating a file instead of creating a .xls file its generates directories

```
//filename = "collectionreport.xls" 
String path  = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+File.separator+fileName;
    
File file = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

try {
   fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
    Log.e(TAG, "Writing file" + file);
    isSuccess = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error writing Exception: ", e);
    isSuccess = false;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to save file due to Exception: ", e);
    isSuccess = false;
}
```

error:

````
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/aa.bb.com.modules.tabbank/files/Download/CollectionReport163548565.xls (Is a directory)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)```
````

EDIT: It automatically worked after restarting my computer running on linux and re installing the application

Comment: Can you give the plain String values of `path`, `fileName` and `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

Comment: path = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/aa.bb.com.modules.tabbank/files/Download/CollectionReport1635487787565.xls
filename = CollectionReport1635487787565.xls
context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/aa.bb.com.modules.tabbank/files/Download/

Comment: Think that you created it yourself testing your code. Delete Download directory and try again.

Comment: still not working by deleting the directory